# Steps to create my own robot

Tags: gazebo, rviz, urdf, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am a beginner user with ROS and I read some tutorials about it and I finished all the beginner level and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Groovy.

My question is: I need the software steps (step by step) of how to build my own robot using ROS? as till now I am NOT knowing how to start to build my own robot, I do not mean how to create robot at general?, I mean What should I learn first in ROS then second then third ...... to create my own designed robot at the final

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67333/steps-to-create-my-own-robot/) by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This answer to your previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/66980/step-by-step-to-build-my-own-robot/?answer=66984#post-id-66984) still sounds valid to me. Please read it thoroughly, consider the suggestions and advices there.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-15**:
And work through the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).